# JS Function returning function for later use - arguments undefined

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a function that can then return many functions based on an input. Here is an example of the problem I am facing.

```
var giveFunction = function(text) {
    return function(text) {
        console.log(text)
    }
}
var test = giveFunction('this is a test');
test()
```

Running test() at the end prints undefined instead of 'this is a test.' Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: invoke it as test("this is a test")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner function should not contain any parameter,

```
var giveFunction = function(text) {
    return function() {
        console.log(text)
    }
}
```

Let it create a closure. If it has a parameter then that would be read during execution and `undefined` would be printed as you are not calling that function with any arguments.

If you want your code to be working then you have to use `bind` for that,

```
var giveFunction = function(text) {
    return function(text) {
        console.log(text)
    }.bind(null, text)
}
var test = giveFunction('this is a test');
test();  //'this is a test'
```

Comment: What is the significance of using bind vs closure in this case? Seems like using closure is the smarter choice here.

Comment: @Elliot I don't understand what you are asking. Closure and bind works in a different way.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any particular reason to go with the bind instead of using closure here, but perhaps that is a whole other stack question in itself. Thank you for the help understanding this!

Comment: @Elliot Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets go one step further and ask why?

```
var outerFunction = function(outerParameter) {
   return innerFunction function(innerParameter) {
     // in here we have access to anything in this function and the outer function
     // all the way to out the the global scope
     // therefore, we dont need to pass innerParameter in again as a parameter! ( in your case we 'next')
   }
  /// now over here, outside of innerFunction, we do NOT have access to innerParameter!
}
```

So applying the above principles to your code we have:

```
var giveFunction = function(text) {
    return function() {
        console.log(text)
    }
}
var test = giveFunction('this is a test');
test()
```

which now works!

Finally, checkout the most upvoted post under the javascript tag:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)